# how i place image on center of screen?

Tags: android

this is my code which place image on top senter of screen how i place image on center of screen?  not top center my screen look like this   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRjbD.jpg

i wanna  place on center of screen not op center

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

  android:layout_width="fill_parent">


   <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
 android:src="@drawable/agapplogo" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"

 android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
android:text="@string/welcome"
android:layout_below="@id/ImageView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TextView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either play with `android:gravity="center"` in `<RelativeLayout>`

OR

include `android:centerInParent="true"` inside ImageView

Comment: it is possible place jusst little above the center of screen?

Comment: sorrry i gve u aceptance :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:  `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



  <ImageView
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it is possible i palce just little above the center??

Answer (score 0):

place `android:gravity="center"` for `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Just give  your ImageView in xml this attribute:

```
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

this may happen due to RelativeLayout,try using LinearLayout